# Hibernate / JPA / JPQL

Tags: java-ee

Есть таблица в БД с меню в котором содержатся название блюда`name` и цена `price`. Как мне вытащить все названия блюд с ценой 200 ?

пробую:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.name FROM Menu c WHERE c.price = 200 ", Menu.class);
ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) query.getResultList();
for (String s : names){
System.out.println(s);
}
```

получаю :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [Menu] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.String]
\tat org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:387)
\tat org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
```

Comment: А вы пробовали вместе только имени вытягивать все колонки либо же вообще не указывать класс, не очень понял зачем он в вашем запросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.name FROM Menu c WHERE c.price = 200 ", String.class);`
или совсем без класса
`Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.name FROM Menu c WHERE c.price = 200 ");`